# Question on Concavity.

Tags: functions

I am struggling to show that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are concave, then $h(x) = \min[f(x),g(x)]$ is concave and also showing that $h(x) = \max[f(x),g(x)]$ need not be concave.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $t \in (0,1)$ with $a < b$ and define $$x = ta + (1-t)b.$$ You must show $$h(x) = h(ta + (1-t)b) > th(a) + (1-t)h(b).$$

If $f(a) < g(a)$, then
$$
h(ta + (1-t)b) \ge f(ta + (1-t)b) > tf(a) + (1-t)f(b)
$$
and if $g(a) < f(a)$ use the same argument on $g$.

Answer (score 0):

As for your second question, take $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x$. Then $h(x)=\max\{f(x),g(x)\}=|x|$, which is obviously not concave.

Comment: Are f(x) = x  and g(x) = -x concave functions here?

Comment: Every linear function is concave.